# Auto update of child document when parent document updates - couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am currently studying couchbase and I have to related documents like the following below:

Parent Document:

```
{
"userId":"testUser",
"password":"password123,
"status":"LOCKED"
}
```

Child Document:

```
{
"dateUpdated":"2014/12/21"
"remarks":"Sample remarks"
"user":{
    "userId":"testUser",
    "password":"password123,
    "status":"LOCKED"
    }
}
```

is it possible for couchbase to auto-update the child document if the are changes on the parent document, like if someone changes the user name or changes the status of the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism in Couchbase to do what you describe. The only way to do this is if you denormalize the data into a single document, so I would consider whether you really need these two entity types as separate documents.

If you absolutely must have this sort of transactional logic, and cannot denormalize the data into a single document, you can look into implementing a two-phase commit. I would recommend against it in most cases, because of the additional complexity and performance cost, but if you must, you must. http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/transactional-logic.html